# laravel5.2 Auth::guest() returns error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to use the inbuilt `Auth` for login in `laravel` and register. These automatically generated pages work so well, now I use `Auth::guest()` to check if the user is authorized to return a view: index else to login page.

But it shows:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found".

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StepsController extends Controller
{
    public function step1()
    {
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }else {
            return view('index');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "import" the definition of the facade of Auth and remove the `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth` because does not exists.

Just add at the top (just before the class declaration):

```
use Auth;
```

And remove the other:

Having this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class StepsController extends Controller
{
....
```

Hope it helps.

PS: If you want to learn Laravel with a good guide, step-by-step, please check here: [Learn Laravel](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-5-course-learn-php-laravel/?couponCode=forum2)

Comment: Thank you, I solve this problem with your answer. "use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;" need to be deleted. I will view your course :)

Comment: Ohh sure! I'm going to edit my answer to reflect that. Best wishes.